# Compojure: How to get query parameters as a map

Tags: clojure, compojure-api

I just created my RESTful service through Luminus using this doc: http://www.luminusweb.net/docs/services.md

Apparently Compojure-API uses Schema library to map the query parameters. However, I would like to be able to get all the query parameters as a single map instead. For instance:

From this `GET /api/myapp?color=green&shape=round&height=100`
to this `{:color "green", :shape "round", :height "100"}`

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.

I used this as an example `(GET "/test" {params :params} (str params))`. `params` is a map with keys and values for the given query params.